# How can I group by specific column in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm new to sharepoint and I have question on how to group by specific column that I have json formatting inside it.

Here the question,
I try to create a category column with this JSON

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$StartDate]> @now, 'Upcoming', if([$EndDate]< @now, 'Expired', 'Due'))"
}
```

and below the issue when try to group by Category,

Mind help point out what I did wrong

Thank you.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any further questions? Please remember to accept helpful answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, group by a list through a JSON formatting column is not available.

JSON formatting is just a expression, it does not fill in values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either use Power Auto or use column formula to automatically populate (default value, etc) and fill the designated column (Category). JSON alone won't populate the column values for you since that just modify the exterior view and group by is based on value.